# What is the easiest way to send text from a child GUI process to a console parent?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application

I've coded two processes using C++. One is the GUI process that is called by my console app using `CreateProcess` API. I need to pass text from the GUI app (child) to the console app (parent.) The amount of text could be arbitrary -- from a few lines to KBs of text.

What is the easiest way to do it?

PS. I have access to the source code of both processes.

Comment: How about [pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ooph. I was looking for something easy... But thanks, I thought of it too.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly you can tell `CreateProcess` to use specific file-handles to use for `stdin`/`stdout` of the new process. You could create an [anonymous pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set the write-handle as the new process' `stdout`, then the new process just have to write to `stdout` (like `std::cout << something`) and the parent process can read that. Using WIN32 file handles is not that hard.

Comment: Why can't you just send a user-defined message to the window?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That is a good idea! The question is how do I get to such output anonymous pipe from a GUI app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GUI application is truly graphical only, you don't really use the standard output stream (i.e. `std::cout`). This can the be reused for output to your console application.

First you need to create an anonymous pipe using [`CreatePipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HANDLE hPipeRead;
HANDLE hPipeWrite;

CreatePipe(&hPipeRead, &hPipeWrite, NULL, 0);
```

Now you have to handles that can be used as a normal file handle; One to read from and the other to write to. The write-handle should be set as the standard output for the new process you create:

```
STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { 0 };
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = hPipeWrite;  // Standard output of the new process
                                      // is set to the write end of the pipe

CreateProcess(
    lpApplicationName,
    lpCommandLine,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &startupInfo,  // Use our startup information
    &processInfo);
```

Now whenever the child process needs to write to the parent, it only have to use standard output:

```
std::cout << "In child process, are you getting this parent?";
```

The parent uses [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read from the read-end of the pipe:

```
char buffer[256];
DWORD bytesRead = 0;

ReadFile(hPipeRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL);
```

**Note:** I haven't done WIN32 programming in some time, so might be wrong on some details. But should hopefully be enough to get you started.

---

There are of course many other ways if [Inter Process Communications (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), including (but not limited to) sockets, files, shared memory, etc.

Comment: Thank you much for the code sample. I'll try it. The only question I have is about the pipe size. When you created it you specified its size as 0. Does this theoretically mean that it can contain as much data as possible? Or is there some default limit?

Comment: @ahmd0 From the linked manual page for `CreatePipe`: "If this parameter is zero, the system uses the default buffer size." Exactly what the default buffer size is I have no idea, but unless you start to send megabytes of data there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the docs. `unless you start to send megabytes of data there should be no problem` -- that is exactly how the problems happen later down the road.

Comment: @ahmd0 For that large amount of data, a file would probably be better, and then use the pipe to just send the filename. But remember that sockets also have buffers counted in kilobytes, and you can still send several gigabytes of data with no problems, as long as the receiver can process the data fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

Console application can create a WinAPI window (non-visible), such that it can receive messages (idea taken from AllocateHWND function in Delphi).

Another solution is to use named pipes.

Another solution is to send data locally via TCP/IP.

If these strings are only a debug ones, consider using OutputDebugString function from WinAPI and capturing them with a program like SysInternals' [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Comment: That's a good idea too. Although, no, this is not for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is probably to make the child actually a console application, even though it also creates windows.

In that case, you can have your parent spawn the child using `_popen`, and the child can just write the output to its normal `stdout`/`std::cout`. `_popen` returns a `FILE *`, so the parent can read the child's output about like it'd normally read a file (well, normally for C anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately there's too much code involved in the GUI app to change it. It'd be easier to implement the pipe server/client approach suggested above.

Comment: There's no way to send that text via some sort of a thread-based WM_COPYDATA message, is there?

Comment: @ahmd0: Converting the GUI app to a console app is fairly simple: rename the startup function from `WinMain` to `main`. They take different parameters, but you usually ignore them anyway. You could do WM_COPYDATA (with PostThreadMessage) but it's kind of ugly. Another possibility would be to have the GUI app write debug messages (`OutputDebugString`) for the parent to intercept (parent would act as a debugger).

Comment: Oooh - same basic idea I just answered - was thrown by your talk about making the child a console app.  Can't GUI apps write to their standard output under Windows anyway?

Comment: @TonyD: They can write to it, but it won't go anywhere -- what they write just gets discarded.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: yikes, that's screwed up.  Thanks for filling me in.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah, I never had luck with `PostThreadMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

Various methods can be used, some of them were given above. Which one is simplest depends on you task.
I can also suggest you **filemapping technics** which is widely used in IPC, and for ex. dll are implemented using filemapping.
It allows **mutliply processes to share the same resources simultaniously**, access is random not consequntial.
**Here are main steps of implementation:**

**1.** Process A creates a file;
**2.** Process A creates a named  system object mappedfile to the file (mappedfile allocates memory);
**3.** Process A creates a system object a viewOfMapped file(this allows to map some area of the process A to the pages in the main memory which were allocated by mappedFile);
**4.** Process B creates the named system object mappedfile(name should be similar to the one of process A used), viewOfMapped file;
**5.** By pointers returned by viewOfMapped processes can share the same memory.
Example:
**Process A:**

```
/* 1. file creation */
    hFile = CreateFile(0, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  CREATE_ALWAYS,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  
    NULL); 

/* 2. Create file mapping */
    wchar_t lpName[] = L"fileMappingObject0";
    HANDLE hfileMappingObject;
    hfileMappingObject = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024, lpName);

/* 3. Create MappedFileViewOfFile */
    void* p = (MapViewOfFile(hfileMappingObject, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0));
```

**Process B:**

```
/* 2. Create file mapping */
        wchar_t lpName[] = L"fileMappingObject0";
        HANDLE hfileMappingObject;
        hfileMappingObject = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024, lpName);

    /* 3. Create MappedFileViewOfFile */
        void* p = (MapViewOfFile(hfileMappingObject, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0));
```

This method is rather simple and also powerfull.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I like file mapping technique myself, except that it comes with two caveats. First off, the size of the mapped memory is finite & limited to a page size. So one needs to code certain marshaling mechanism to manage the transfer. And secondly, if processes are running with different elevation levels one needs to set up security descriptor from an elevated process first, and that may create a nasty race condition. Other than that it's probably the fastest IPC.